# Does JSF use List or Array for internal use?

Tags: jsf

I'm trying to figure out if I should use lists or array with JSF.
I know it accepts both, but I would like to also be efficient.

I'm referring to instances where lists/arrays are passed to JSF, for example:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.array}" />
```

Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it. If there is a performance difference, it would be negligible. Use the data structure that best fits your needs.

Comment: @GaryBuyn yeah... but if JSF actually converts from one type of container to the other and it's of large size, it could cost a bunch to convert it.

Comment: It will probably adapt the value using a [model](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/javax/faces/model/package-summary.html) type.

Comment: @McDowell Interesting, I didn't consider that option. I'll try to look it up (If it's what it actually does)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSF doesn't convert anything. Both are equally good supported. JSF will just wrap the value in a suitable [`DataModel`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/model/DataModel.html) implementation to keep track of the iterated row. See also the source code of `UIRepeat` (below is from Mojarra):

```
private DataModel getDataModel() {
    if (this.model == null) {
        Object val = this.getValue();
        if (val == null) {
            this.model = EMPTY_MODEL;
        } else if (val instanceof DataModel) {
            this.model = (DataModel<Object>) val;
        } else if (val instanceof List) {
            this.model = new ListDataModel<Object>((List<Object>) val);
        } else if (Object[].class.isAssignableFrom(val.getClass())) {
            this.model = new ArrayDataModel<Object>((Object[]) val);
        } else if (val instanceof ResultSet) {
            this.model = new ResultSetDataModel((ResultSet) val);
        } else {
            this.model = new ScalarDataModel<Object>(val);
        }
    }
    return this.model;
}
```

Just choose whatever value type is the best and easiest to maintain. Profile if necessary. Plain arrays have a littler memory footprint, but they are also harder to maintain (adding/removing items should happen by `System#arrayCopy()`, for example). It would maybe only make sense for static collections, but not for dynamic collections.

If you want to go for premature optimization, then you should probably not be using JSF at all, but just plain vanilla JSP/Servlet and work with primitives and plain arrays only :)

Memory is cheap nowadays though.